# How should I save the comments in visual studio code using comments api?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

Once I create the comments in the visual studio code using comments API. Again, I closed and open the visual studio code. But, the comments was not over there. How should I save the comments?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Could you post the code you've written so far, as well as explanations of your attempts to solve this problem yourself? StackOverflow is less intended for open-ended "how would you do this" kinds of questions, and more "why isn't what I'm trying working" kinds of questions.

Comment: Thanks for reply mypost, I have used git hub link for sample code :https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/main/comment-sample/src/extension.ts

Comment: Pls help me I was stuck these concepts,Thank you